# How to create SQL Server jobs without access to "msdb" or "master" databases?

Tags: sql, sql-server, jobs

I'm using SSMS 2014 and I have not any permission to access `msdb` or `master` on my host and I just have permission to use my owned database's stored procedures and functions and I want to create a job that contains some steps and repeats every day at 4:00 AM.

I found some stored procedures like `sys.sp_sqlagent_add_job` and `sys.sp_sqlagent_add_jobstep` but I don't know how to use these stored procedures  and how to set schedule for my job using them.

Comment: Ask someone that does have permission to do this for you. Once created, you (or this other person) can create a script of the job if needed.

Comment: The permissions are there for a reason. You're asking how to bypass them, which if possible, would be a flaw in the security design.

Comment: You can't. But there's no reason you can't use a scheduler somewhere else (Windows Event Scheduler, some kind of serverless scheduler in AWS or Azure) that connects to your database and does work.